# How to add space before a letter using a formula

Tags: excel-formula

How to add a space using an excel formula after a number or before an alphabet?
e.g 1:30PM --> 1:30 PM

Comment: Do you need a formula?  You could just use cell formatting...

Comment: yes i need a formula

Comment: If it is just AM and PM you are interested in adding the space before then `=substitute(substitute(A1,"PM"," PM"),"AM"," AM")` or does it need to be anything after a number and before a letter?

Comment: that will do thanks !

Comment: If you need a space after a number (or a time including a colon) and the string could be ANYTHING then this might work: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",": "),"0","0 "),"1","1 "),"2","2 "),"3","3 "),"4","4 "),"5","5 "),"6","6 "),"7","7 "),"8","8 "),"9","9 ")," :",":")," 0","0")," 1","1")," 2","2")," 3","3")," 4","4")," 5","5")," 6","6")," 7","7")," 8","8")," 9","9")
`

Comment: Of course you could use the Edit Find/Replace function on a selection or the whole sheet as needed... Find "AM, Replace with " AM" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by **Jerry Jeremiah**

If it is just AM and PM you are interested in adding the space before then

```
=substitute(substitute(A1,"PM"," PM"),"AM"," AM")
```

If you need a space after a number (or a time including a colon) and the string could be ANYTHING then this might work: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",": "),"0","0 "),"1","1 "),"2","2 "),"3","3 "),"4","4 "),"5","5 "),"6","6 "),"7","7 "),"8","8 "),"9","9 ")," :",":")," 0","0")," 1","1")," 2","2")," 3","3")," 4","4")," 5","5")," 6","6")," 7","7")," 8","8")," 9","9")`